# How to scale down UIElement in WPF and see what's originaly outside the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scale

I got an UIElement who's bigger than the place it need to take. But when i scale down it using a renderTransform, the part of the element originaly hide , stay hide.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Width="600" Height="500" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve the scale and gets all the UIElement ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but have you tried LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform?

Comment: How damn, it's that this simple. Thank's a lot i try so many thing but don't even think about it. It work just find with LayoutTransform.

Answer (score -1):

An example to illustrate the solution you recieved in comment would be :
If you have a coloured rectangle with a text inside and you do a 90° rotation:

- With LayoutTransform, you would get the rectangle rotated and the text inside would look normal, since the transformation is applied before calculating the content
- With RenderTransform, you would get the rectangle rotated and the text inside rotated as well, since the rectangle AND the text would be generated before doing the rotation.

For your example it gives:

- With LayoutTransform, you scale the area, and then calculate its possible content
- With RenderTransform, you calculate the content, and then scale both area AND its content.

Comment: Thank for your explanation

Comment: The "explanation" is wrong, however. The assumed "*text inside*" element can't be a child of a Rectangle, so transforming the Rectangle would never affect it. Transforming a potential parent element of both a Rectangle and e.g. a TextBlock would transform both the Rectangle and the text with either Layout- or RenderTransform. The difference between Layout- and RenderTransform is simply that the former affects the layout bounds of the transformed element, while the latter does not do that.